# How to stop gitlab-ci in yaml file?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm a junior using for the first time gitlab-ci. I have one repository with two folders/apps and would like to stop automatic builds/deployments with each commit in one of apps changing the following gitlab-ci file configuration:

I have added `builds: false` like in the documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/enable_or_disable_ci.html

But don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```yaml
default_projects_features:
  builds: false

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
 - build
 - deploy

build:
    image: node:latest
    stage: build
    script:
      - npm install --quiet
      - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --progress false
    except:
      - tags

do_publish:
  image: docker:stable
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - apk update && apk add bash
  script:
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default_projects_features` is a site-wide admin feature. It makes no sense in `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

If you want to disable builds on a branch, you can:

- Delete `.gitlab-ci.yml`
- Prefix all of your job names with a dot:

  ```yaml
  .build:
      image: node:latest
      ...
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much @Jonathon Reinhart, I didn't know we can comment yaml parameters with a dot without breaking anything. I also set `.do_publish`